# Plugin to find tree like structures for functions in a JavaScript Project

Tags: javascript, plugins

Is there a plugin available by which we can list down all the user defined functions and their dependent ones as a tree like structures (what '*tree -R*' command gives for directories in unix) for a Javascript Project ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about a plugin for your IDE, most IDE's have this built in. In VSCode it is under outline:
[image: Picture of outline view in VSCode]

In WebStorm is is under structure:
[image: Structure View in WebStorm]

In most IDEs, if they support language highlighting, they probably support this kind of view

Comment: Will it show all the dependent functions also ?
P.S : Sorry for late reply.

Comment: Yeah, so in VSCode the purple boxes are functions and the blue boxes are variables, while in WebStorm, the blue c is a constant, the orange f is a function, the red m is a method, and the p is a parameter. For a full list of these symbols you can look at this site: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html

Comment: Ok Alright ! Is there any way out to see the same for a whole project so that we can understand which function have been called by other functions which are left alone ?

Comment: I don't believe so, sorry